# Запуск приложения без фокуса

Tags: c++, winapi, visual-c++

Есть необходимость в крошечном приложении, которое будет выполнять команду типа "Somepath\someApp.exe "someArguments" и сразу закрываться. Нужно сделать вызов таким образом, чтобы это не было заметно глазу. То есть, не появлялось никаких окон, не выпадал фокус из активного окна (даже если он будет сразу возвращаться). По задумке это элемент управления для rainmeter, который будет передавать некие аргументы в активные скины. Например во время игры горячей клавишей вызывается программа, и меняется позиция нужного скина на "поверх всех окон" без сворачивания самой игры. Я чет совсем тупенький, объясните на пальцах, пожалуйста, как это можно сделать. :( спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

Пишите свою программу как стандартную оконную программу (не консольную!), но никаких окон не создавайте. Такая программа не будет видна ни на экране, ни в панели задач.

```
#include "windows.h"

int APIENTRY _tWinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPTSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow) {
    // Разбираем командную строку в lpCmdLine (если надо)
    // Делаем здесь что надо делать
    return 0;
}
```